# Liferay 7.2.1 - Portlet API upgrade in fragment-host

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

I'm asking a question about portlet version 2.0 and 3.0 in the fragment-host.
I'm using Liferay 7.2.1 GA2.

For example, this one :

```
Fragment-Host: com.liferay.users.admin.web;bundle-version="4.0.27"
```

In the init.jsp, I have :

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet" %>
```

But since Liferay 7.1, it should be (cf Breaking Changes) :

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://xmlns.jcp.org/portlet_3_0" prefix="portlet" %>
```

For now I don't made this change and I've the following error : **Requires 3.0 opt-in**

Do I made this change or is there another solution ?

Thanks,

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With a fragment, you'll update/modify a JSP that belongs to a (typically) stock portlet. This overriding JSP needs to follow the standard that the overridden portlet sets.

In other words: If you try to provide a Portlet-2.0-spec JSP to a Portlet following the 3.0 specs, you might not find what you expect, and apparently get the error message that you report.

In general: If you override JSPs, you're dealing with implementation level changes to the code that Liferay delivers - there's a lot of maintenance effort connected to it, and this is one of the prices you'll have to pay

Comment: So Liferay 7.2.1 GA2 give a 'com.liferay.users.admin.web' with '4.0.27' version. Its init.jsp contains Portlet-2.0 spec. I let it that way or it should be updated ?

Comment: I've assumed the mismatch based on your question - there's still another chance for a mismatch, if you build your fragment with portlet-spec 3, but for portlet-spec 2 (e.g. the other way around from what I assumed in my answer). You should be able to figure this out when you look at your buildfiles